# Porting Android on Set top box

Tags: android

I am trying to port Android on an IP Set top box.

Can anyone help me in creating the *vendor folder (product and board definition files)*? I've successfully compiled and ported the bootloader (u-boot) and linux kernel (2.6.34) with required drivers.

I'm stuck at creating this **vendor folder**.

Answer (score 0):

Android source website has details on how to create your vendor directory here:

http://source.android.com/porting/build_system.html